# How can i set a variable from a function called through a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanna do something like this:

```
def setimg():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=r'Images',
                                          title = 'Choose file',
                                          filetypes = (('png files','*.png'),('jpg files','*.jpg')))

    myimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    return myimg

Image1 = setimg()
Image2 = setimg()
```

This but via a button. Something like

```
chooseImage = Button(root,text='Choose Image',command= Image1 = setimg())
```

The above code doesnt work obviously

Thanks

Comment: instead of returning the value, set it as a global name, `global Image1` at the start of the function and then in the function do `Image1 = ImageTk....`

Comment: What is `openf()` Is that supposed to be `setimg()`?

Comment: @Matiiss He has multple global variables, he doesn't want to hard-code a specific one into the function.

Comment: Define separate functions that assign each of the global variables, and use those functions in the `command=`.

Comment: it is a bit confusing what you want your end goal to be, can't you just add them to a list or dictionary?

Comment: The main problem with supplied code is the use of `askopenfile(` which will return an open file. You need to use `askopenfilename(` to return the path.

Comment: Yes ive edited the `askopenfile(`  to `askopenfilename(`. And also openf() to setimg(). But i still cant solve the problem. I wanna create a program thats asks the user for a image (which will be assigned to variable img1) and then another image (through another button) assigned to the var img2 to be used as a watermark. I think I can only use lists if i assume that the user presses the buttons in a certain order. Sorry if i wasnt clear initially

Comment: I've made a slight change to original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in a list as suggested by @Matiiss will enable open ended number of images to be preloaded.
This modification uses one button for multiple purposes, first to choose image then choose watermark then select to view images.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = []

root = tk.Tk()

opener = tk.Button(root, text = 'Choose Image')
opener.grid(sticky = tk.EW)

def view():
    opener.destroy()
    forground, watermark = image
    # Display 

def setimg():
    path = fido.askopenfilename(
        title = 'Choose image',
        filetypes = (('png files', '*.png'), ('jpg files', '*.jpg')))
    if path:
        imagename = Image.open(path)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = imagename)
        image.append(photo)
        imagename.close()
        if len(image) == 2:
            opener.config(text = 'View Images', command = view)
        else:
            opener.config(text = 'Choose Watermark')

opener["command"] = setimg
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wanna create a program thats asks the user for a image and then another image (through another button) to be used as a watermark. I think I can only use lists if i assume that the user presses the buttons in a certain order. Sorry if i wasnt clear initially

Comment: Create another button exactly like the first except use a different text message like 'Choose Watermark'.

Comment: In your answer youve created a single button and are changing the text. But what if the user selects the wrong image in first try and then needs to select another. I dont know how to use lists with 2 buttons. If i assume that the user presses each button exactly once and in certain order only then I can set variable using `img =  images[0]` and `watermark = images[1]` but i dont want to make this assumption

Comment: I was finally able to do it with dictionaries. I passed the name of the image variable (`command = lambda: setimg('image')` and `command = lambda:setimg('Watermark')`) through `setimg(name)` and then used images[name] = photo. Thanks for your help